# How to calculate sensitivity, specificity, and odds ratio?

Tags: biostatistics, bioinformatics, clinical-trials

I am trying to calculate sensitivity, specificity, and odds ratio of a data set, they are numerical values of percentages from 0% to 100%.  How should I do the calculation?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) has the formula:
$$sensitivity = \frac{true~positives}{{true~positives + false~negatives}}$$

How should I use this formula in my case?  For example, say I want to calculate sensitivity, I have `<55%` as my cut-off.

My data look like this:

```
27.23, 30.09, 49.69, 74.16, 45.54, 38.45, 38.32, 48.98, 40.14, 35.37
```

in percent.  And my cut-off is `58%`.

I want to calculate the sensitivity and specificity.

Comment: We can't read your mind. If you don't tell us what you've got, all we can say is "yes, that formula is correct for sensitivity" and you can find one for specificity.

odds ratios, though, are not percentages and do not range from 0 to 100. They range from 0 to infinity

Answer (score 0):

To compute any and all of these performance measures you first need a well-defined classification rule.  That means setting a threshold for your rule.  Then it is simple enough to apply the rule to a test set of data and simply count the proportions as they are defined for sensitivity and specificity as well as positive and negative predictive value.

Perhaps the main issue is what do select for the test data set.